# Is it possible to deactivate 'Sonar way' quality profile from an analysis?

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

I would like to analyse my code only against a [Finbug quality profile](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs).

In order to simplify the issues reading, I would like to deactivate the default 'Sonar way' profile or at least to filter its rules out. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4):

When you're connected to Sonar. Go to `quality profiles` tab

Then select the profile "sonar way" and create new copy of it . Because Sonarqube does not allow us to change the root profile, if you want to modify the rules set, you need your own rules.

[image]

Then select the new profile and deactivate rules you don't want.

Finally set this new profile as the default one.